# Best to handle communication between Marionette modules without violating Law of Demeter

Tags: backbone.js, ecmascript-6, marionette, backbone-events, backbone-routing

I’m currently working on rewriting our Marionette codebase using ES6 and Marionette v3.

I created a couple of submodules (`ProductShowRoute`, `CartManager`, etc.) which are all started from my main `App`.

I was wondering how you guys are managing the communication between modules. In our previous Marionette apps, communication was too hectic and too much was being sent around using `Backbone.Wreqr`.

When a user adds a product to their cart, our `ProductsModule` needs to let the `CartModule` know about this. How are you organizing this communication without writing too much spaghetti code? `Backbone.Radio` / `Backbone.Wreqr` are great tools, but when used incorrectly (or too much things happening in between modules) it’s hard to know which events end up where.

Also, I’m wondering how you are changing routes. I read a blog post by Derick Bailey who warned for the use of `App.navigate(‘route’, { trigger: true })` but in [Marionette Wires](https://github.com/thejameskyle/marionette-wires/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=trigger%3Atrue) I saw this happening a couple of times. Is `trigger: true` really this bad to use? And what alternatives do we have? We used `Backbone.Wreqr` for this before, which calls the `Router` of each module and changes the route, but that seems like a lot of communication going back and forth as well.

Thanks a lot!

Vernon

Answer (score 0):

For communication between subApps, I like each subApp to trigger a method on their channel indicating their action, then have an event registry somewhere on the App. I like to do this so I can clearly see a list of actions when an event is fired. Also, in my opinion it shouldnt be the ProductsModules concern what happens after the event is fired

```
// Fire an event.
ProductsModuleChannel.trigger('product:added', productModel);

// Event Registry
App.listenTo(ProductModuleChannel, 'product:added', function (productModel) {
    CartManager.addProduct(productModel)
})
```

In regards to `App.navigate('route', {trigger: true});` I don't like applications to be 'route driven'. Routes should be an entry point to an application, but thats it. I tend to do something like the following

```
...
showSomePage: function () {
    // Render some views and do other things

    // Update the route
    App.navigate('myRoute'); // Note no 'trigger: true'
}
```

Hope this helps